# how can i optimize this mysql statement, it is very slow

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

```sql
select _id as Id, concat_ws(' ',last_name,first_name) as name, (select title from posts_log where (_id = p.id_2)) as post, 
            (select count(_id) from profile_details where (profile_type = 'Client' and id_2 = p._id and ${dateRange('creation_date',fromDate,toDate)} and _status = 'Active')) as regs, 
            (select count(_id) from profile_details where (profile_type = 'Client' and id_2 = p._id and ${dateRange('closure_date',fromDate,toDate)} and _status = 'Exited')) as quits, 
            (select count(_id) from profile_details where (profile_type = 'Client' and id_2 = p._id and _status = 'Active')) as clients, 
            (select count(_id) from profile_details where (profile_type = 'Client' and id_2 = p._id and _status = 'Exited')) as closedClients, 
            (select count(_id) from profile_details where (profile_type = 'Center' and id_2 = p._id and _status = 'Active')) as centers, 
            (select count(_id) from profile_details where (profile_type = 'Center' and id_2 = p._id and _status = 'Exited')) as closedCenters, 
            (select ifnull(sum(loan_amount),0) as amount from loan_accounts la where (la._status = 'Active' and (date(la.disbursement_date) >= date('01-01-2022') and date(la.disbursement_date) <= date('01-31-2022')) and la.profile_id in (select _id from profile_details where (id_2 = p._id)))) as disbs, 
            (select ifnull(sum(amount),0) from transactions_log tl where (tl._status = 'Applied' and tl.transaction_type = 'Deposit' and (date(tl.entry_date) >= date('01-01-2022') and date(tl.entry_date) <= date('01-31-2022')) and tl.account_id in (select _id from savings_accounts where (profile_id in (select _id from profile_details where (id_2 = p._id)))))) as deposits, 
            (select ifnull(sum(abs(amount)),0) from transactions_log where (_status = 'Applied' and transaction_type = 'Withdrawal' and (date(tl.entry_date) >= date('01-01-2022') and date(tl.entry_date) <= date('01-31-2022')) and account_id in (select _id from savings_accounts where (profile_id in (select _id from profile_details where (id_2 = p._id)))))) as withdrawals, 
            (select ifnull(sum(amount),0) from transactions_log where (_status = 'Applied' and (transaction_type = 'Repayment' or transaction_type = 'Write Off') and (date(tl.entry_date) >= date('01-01-2022') and date(tl.entry_date) <= date('01-31-2022')) and account_id in (select _id from loan_accounts where (profile_id in (select _id from profile_details where (id_2 = p._id)))))) as repayments, 
            (select ifnull(sum(expected_repayment_amount),0) from schedules_log where (_status in ('Pending','Partially Paid','Arrears') and expected_repayment_amount > 0 and (date(tl.entry_date) >= date('01-01-2022') and date(tl.entry_date) <= date('01-31-2022')) and account_id in (select _id from loan_accounts where (profile_id in (select _id from profile_details where (id_2 = p._id)))))) as defaults, 
            (select ifnull(sum(abs(balance)),0) as amount from savings_accounts where (_status = 'Active' and profile_id in (select _id from profile_details where (id_2 = p._id)))) as savings, 
            (select ifnull(sum(abs(balance)),0) as amount from loan_accounts where (_status = 'Active' and profile_id in (select _id from profile_details where (id_2 = p._id)))) as loan, 
            (select ifnull(sum(expected_repayment_amount),0) as amount from schedules_log where (_status in ('Pending','Partially Paid','Arrears') and expected_repayment_amount > 0 and date(expected_repayment_date) < date(now()) and account_id in (select _id from loan_accounts where (profile_id in (select _id from profile_details where (id_2 = p._id)))))) as totalDefaults 
            from profile_details p where (p._id in (1042239621,1307205751,2458884621));
```

Comment: Hint: `EXPLAIN`. Note that queries this big, with this many subselects, are not going to be fun to optimize. Use `JOIN`.

Comment: Tip: Before going down the road of optimizing this, check that you have **all the required indexes in place** and that you've **tuned your server as best you can**. An untuned, stock-config server will perform like garbage.

Comment: @tadman pls what do u mean by tuning my server?

Comment: [Documentation explains](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimization.html).

Comment: this query requires 5 different tables, to use join is kinda complicated for me

Comment: Might seem like that, but it's less complicated than whatever you've got going on here.

Comment: I can't talk for MySQL (your incorrect SQL Server tag brought me here) but I doubt all those subqueries are good for performance (they wouldn't be in SQL Server).

Comment: [A visual explanation of SQL joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/), which helped me when I started out 15ish years ago with SQL.

Comment: All those subqueries require separate access and should be optimized separately. However, I would start with the most basic optimization. Change `from profile_details p where (p._id in (1042239621,1307205751,2458884621));`. Change the `in` operator to an `=` operator by separating the query into three separate queries, as in `from profile_details p where p._id = 1042239621;`. Then just `union` them.

Comment: i tot using in is beta than using = operator and multiple or clauses

Comment: and also i used the in operator bcos i'm not in control of the numbers of profile ids that will be in the array the in operator is checking from, i got that from the application level not mysql

Comment: Turn the `IN( SELECT ...)` into `JOIN`.  What does `${dateRange('creation_date',fromDate,toDate)}` expand to?  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`  Shouldn't there be a `GROUP BY` near the end?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for at least the outer table and one of each type of inner table.

Comment: Whenever you ask about SQL query optimization, **show the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query is slow because it is actually 16 x 3 = 48 queries. You have 16 SELECT [correlated subqueries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) in your main SELECT query, and you're looking up three values of `p._id`.

Your first step is to transform at least some of those subqueries into independent subqueries and JOIN them. (This is a vital skill for people who use SQL.)

I'll show you how to refactor a couple of them.

First, the easy one -- the post title. Just LEFT JOIN your `posts_log` table to your `profile_details` table ON the appropriate id values.

```sql
SELECT profile_details._id AS Id, 
       CONCAT(' ', p.last_name, p.first_name) AS name,
       posts_log.title AS post
  FROM profile_details p
  LEFT JOIN posts_log    ON posts_log._id = p._id2
 WHERE p.id_2 IN  (1042239621,1307205751,2458884621);
```

Next, let us write a subquery to retrieve your your `regs` column in your result set.  This aggregating (GROUP BY) subquery generates the `regs` value for each value of `_id_2` in the table.

```sql
                    SELECT id_2, COUNT (_id) AS regs
                    FROM profile_details
                    WHERE profile_type = 'Client'
                      AND _status = 'Active'
                      AND ${ dateRange('creation_date', fromDate, toDate) }
                    GROUP BY id_2
```

Then you LEFT JOIN that subquery in your main query, and SELECT the result.

```sql
SELECT profile_details._id AS Id, 
       CONCAT(' ', p.last_name, p.first_name) AS name,
       posts_log.title AS post,
       regs.regs
  FROM profile_details p
  LEFT JOIN posts_log    
            ON posts_log._id = p._id2
  LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT id_2, COUNT (_id) AS regs
                    FROM profile_details
                    WHERE profile_type = 'Client'
                      AND _status = 'Active'
                      AND ${ dateRange('creation_date', fromDate, toDate) }
                    GROUP BY id_2
            ) regs
            ON regs.id_2 = p._id2
 WHERE p.id_2 IN  (1042239621,1307205751,2458884621);
```

That's the pattern to use.

(I am confused about whether your `_id` values start with underscores or not. You didn't show us your table definitions so it's hard for me to get that right. Also, I assume the `${ date_range ... }` stuff expands to a valid SQL date-range filter.)